# Convert SQL query to LINQ method syntax in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq

I want to get data from 4 tables that have a relationship with each other.

**scenario:** A person can be loan a device that belongs to a certain program

```
      Database Tables
person          -> Persons Database Table           
device loan     -> Loan Database Table  
device          -> Devices Database Table  
program         -> Programs Database Table
```

These are the database tables in a diagram:

[image: These are the database tables in a diagram:]

This is the desired output:
[image: This is the desired output:]

The output above was produced by the following SQL query :

```
SELECT A.*, 
COALESCE(ps.first_name,'') AS firstname,
COALESCE(ps.last_name,'') AS lastname,
COALESCE(p.program_name, '') AS program_Name 
FROM devices A 
LEFT JOIN device_loans l ON l.device_id = A.device_id
LEFT JOIN persons ps ON ps.person_id = l.person_id
LEFT JOIN programs p ON A.program_id = p.program_id
WHERE A.device_type ="Tablet" AND  p.program_id = 5;
```

I want to Convert the SQL query to LINQ method syntax. I have try the
folloing method :

```
var devices = from ds in _context.Devices
        join p in _context.Programs on ds.ProgramID equals p.Id 
        join l in _context.DeviceLoan on ds.Id equals l.device_id 
        join ps in _context.Persons on l.device_id equals ps.Id 
        where ds.Type == typeName
        where ds.ProgramID == id
        select new Device
              {
                  Id = ds.Id,
                  ProgramID = p.Id,
                  Type = ds.Type,
                  Serial_Number = ds.Serial_Number,
                  Label = ds.Label,
                  Price = ds.Price,
                  Purchase_Date = ds.Purchase_Date,
                  Device_Status = ds.Device_Status
                  
              };
```

What I want is to create a **LINQ method Syntax** that include the **Firstname and Lastname** from the **Database Persons Table**, **Database Programs Table** and data from **Database Devices Table** just like the **SQL query above**.

```
Output: I want all devices of a certain program, loan or not loan with 
        first name & last name of a Person loan too.
```

Thank you for Your help

Comment: I think that your problem is that you are not doing a left join, to see how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Use linqpad for converting sql to linq and vice versa. This is just a application just install and you can write queries. https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: @RahulShukla I don't think LINQPad goes from sql to Linq. It will do Linq to sql.

Comment: If you post classes, i’ll help you to convert this to LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. I created the following query and it gives me what I wanted.

```
var devices = _context.Devices.
                    Where(c => c.Type == typeName && c.ProgramID == id).
                    Include(c => c.Program).
                    Include(c => c.DeviceLoans)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Persons).
                    ToList();
```

in the .cshtml

var loan_object = item.DeviceLoans.Where(d=>d.device_id==item.Id).FirstOrDefault<Device_Loan>()

To get the name of the person that the device is a loan to, I use the above line of code.